# Svn Move does not show up in context menu

Tags: tortoisesvn

I've committed changes and updated and my directory looks good to go. But when I right-click a file I want to move into another folder, I see all options such as svn delete, etc. except for svn move.  I can't figure out why I do not see the move option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to move a file, you can just right-click and drag the file to the new location. You will get a menu when you release the file from which you can choose from svn move and svn copy.